# KKT condition and linear program

Tags: linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Since all linear program all convex, and the Slater's condition always hold for linear programs. Is it always possible to solve the linear programs with KKT conditions? because it will convert the problem to solving set of linear equations. If not, why?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, and the whole [interior point methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method) exploit that

Comment: thanks for the comment, yes I noticed that when I went through it.